# toggleClass Complete Dom Change

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a toggleClass which toggles a class based which in turn changes the background position of the sprite.

To Confirm:

- Animation works fine
- Toggleclass - toggles the classes on and off
- other CSS reacts fine

Problem:

If I keep double clicking the icon the animation can't keep up. In my case the icon is a green plus and red hypen. The inner content vertically opens and closes. The icon toggle class is

```
.active
```

However if I keep clicking the icon the class becomes present on a collapsed state of my accordion. When in fact it should be closed:

```
Collapsed -> no class
Open      -> toggleClass adds .active
```

If I double click the class again the bug gets negated.

I have seen somewhere a method or code addition to force the toggle to complete? Is this possible? As I think the fast clicking is skips class addition or removal, of the class above..

any help is welcomed!

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: old post, this is all sorted now. Thanks for the reply @MelanciaUK.